# this pointer and destructor being called

Tags: c++

I have a number of classes (A,B,C,D,E,...) that use a class X as one of their constructor arguments. 
Taking E class only as an example, other classes are almost similar

```
class E:public D
{
public:
   E(X& x):D(x)
   {
     //do something
   }
};

class X
{
   public:
      void func(int i) 
      {
         if(0==i)
         {
            //constructing other classes by passing in the *this pointer
         }//everything ends here even X
      }
};
```

At the end of the conditional block as shown in the above class `X`, `X` is also destroyed. This is what I think why right after the block ends, I have an error of access violation and exception being thrown at`memory.xx` file @line 116

```
    void _Decref()
    {   // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Mtx, _Uses) == 0)
        {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
        _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
        }
    }
```

In each of the class (A,B, C...) I have several class members defined as `shared_ptr` . What do you think the error is caused by ?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide next time a full functional sample with the proper class attributes. Your question is hardly understandable. But anyway, here your mistake:

You do not provide a pointer, you do give a reference:

```
E(X& x):D(x)
{
  //do something
}
```

In fact you give away the instance itself, not a pointer! At the end of lifetime of `E`, all instances inseide `E` will be destroyed, even `X`. C++ do not care that you have the instance referenced on different places, because C++ has not a something like a reference counter.

Use

```
E(X *x):D(x)
{
  //do something
}
```

I recommend using `std::shared_ptr`.